# Android, XML view file and backend in Java, how can i create my custom view with backend java?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-layout

As we have main.xml file for view and another file java in src folder which contains the events, i have made another view, that onclicking a  button in main.xml it will open the other view xml which should have a java backend file, when i create my custom view xml, then its backened file doesnot create, and how can i click a button and open a new view with another form, just like we do in web pages and how can our custom view have a java backend file.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: Should i have to make a activity for some java class and xml, and should i have to pass it in intent, i saw the tutorial but i am bit confused help!!!

Comment: You are starting android from zero ... program execution happens in activity .. you may have 1 activity with multiple xml or multiple activities with multiple xmls! anyway find tutorial

Comment: Yes i am starting from zero. I just want, if i click on any button a new form should appear, i am very much confused with this long lecture. This phenomena is very simple in .Net and java. You can post Answer, i can rate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML FILES**

1. `firstXML.xml`
2. `secondXML.xml`

**FILES**

`firstActivity.java`

```
public class firstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstXML);
    }
}
```

`secondActivity.java`

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondXML);
    }
}
```

---

Now if you have [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) in `firstXML`. You want this Button to launch secondActivity:

`firstActivity.java`

```
public class firstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstXML);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Some extra notes:
Now if you want `firstActivity` to send some info to `secondActivity`

Change

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

to

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
Bundle muBundle = new Bundle(); //create a Bundle
myBundle.putString("username","Sherif");
myBundle.putInt("userid",1234);
// EXAMINE THE [Bundle Class][2]
myIntent.putExtras(myBundle); //PUT THE Bundle you created in the Intent
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

To capture this data in the `secondActivity`

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondXML);
        Bundle myBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras(); //You got the bundle
        //TO USE THE BUNDLE
        String A = myBundle.getString("username"); // A = "Sherif"
        int B = myBundle.getInt("userid"); // B = 1234
    }
}
```