# create a list view in android and if click it goes to next activity

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to go to a particular activity on list item click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click)

after clicking a listitem how i can go the next activity ?
I have a listview where three items are there when i click one item it call next activity

Comment: check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896590/android-xml-view-file-and-backend-in-java-how-can-i-create-my-custom-view-with/6908797#6908797

Comment: This a really simple question and you could simply search StackOverFlow for questions like this, cause here are lots of them already answered. Please try to search before you ask something in future. Best regards!

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289227/how-to-go-to-a-particular-activity-on-list-item-click

Comment: isn't it a bit harsh to -4 someone's first question, really? - constructive witty criticism in comments should suffice

Comment: @Payal Never ask questions in stackOverflow without searching...

Answer (score 0):

Call this on click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this is a *big time* duplicate

Comment: @Sherif, I'm aware of it, I've mentioned it above. Can't I however answer such a question?

Comment: I wish you at least put some effort in the answer. It is not even suitable for this case

Comment: The problem is not with the one who answered but with the one who questioned ,SO is only for helping others

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for each item in listview set on click listner

```
listitem01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    NextActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

             finish();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
switch(position)
{
case 0:
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)); break;
case 1:
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)); break;
case 2:
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)); break;
}

}
```